# Problemas al ejecutar un proceso donde utilizo el bucle: REPEAT

Tags: mysql

Tengo problemas al ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE INFO_LINEAS()
   BEGIN 
             DECLARE contador_fecha INT;
             DECLARE fecha_actual DATE;


                  SET contador_fecha=(SELECT hml_aniomesinfo from cosechas);
             SET fecha_actual= CAST('2016-12-31' as DATE)

             REPEAT 

                  INSERT INTO cosechas (id_ml) values (id_ml);
                  SET contador_fecha=DATE_ADD(contador_fecha,interval 1 month);

             UNTIL contador_fecha= fecha_actual END REPEAT;

DELIMITER ;

CALL INFO_LINEAS();
```

Mi intención es agregar el número de filas necesarias a cada cliente hasta llegar al la fecha actual=201612. Pero me marca error al momento de ejecutar el programa.

Comment: No veo el `END;` para marcar el final del procedimiento.

Comment: También esta mal la sintaxis `DELIMITER ;`. Se escribe sin espacio, es decir, `DELIMITER;` y justo en la linea anterior esta faltando `//`.

Comment: Te refieres a qué "//" va después del "END" o de "END REPEAT"

Comment: @Marcos: `DELIMITER ;` con espacio está bien. Pero lo demás, no tanto :)

Comment: @Angélica después del `END REPEAT;` debería haber un salto de línea y luego colocar `END;` para cerrar el procedimiento.

Comment: Pregunta: ¿cuántos registros devuelve el query `SELECT hml_aniomesinfo from cosechas`? Puede que allí salga un problema.

Comment: @sstan, es verdad. Tambien falta un `;` al finalizar la linea `SET fecha_actual...`

Comment: @sstan Perdón, soy muy novata. Empecé la semana pasada a utilizar sql, soy nueva en la programación.

Comment: @Angélica: Lo bueno es que estás haciendo el esfuerzo. Mientras compartas lo que has intentado en tus preguntas (como lo has hecho ahora), verás que la comunidad SOes será muy amable y paciente :)